# Undefined method under nested resource in active admin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

I have 2 models  `Tool::Cvt::RemoteFocu` and  `Tool::Cvt::RemoteFocuLog`

`Tool::Cvt::RemoteFocu` has_many  `Tool::Cvt::RemoteFocuLog`

and each `Tool::Cvt::RemoteFocuLog` has one `snapshot` for showing image (which handled by paperclip)

I want to show snapshots in  `Tool::Cvt::RemoteFocu` but I got undefined method error.

```
undefined method `snapshot' for nil:NilClass
```

But actually each record in  `Tool::Cvt::RemoteFocuLog` has this `snapshot` method.

```
ActiveAdmin.register Tool::Cvt::RemoteFocu do

   f.inputs "Remote focus images" do
     f.has_many :remote_focu_logs do |p|
       p.input :snapshot, :as => :file, :label => "Image",:hint => p.object.snapshot.nil? ? p.template.content_tag(:span, "No Image Yet") : p.template.image_tag(p.object.snapshot.url(:small))
       p.input :_destroy, :as=>:boolean, :required => false, :label => 'Remove image'
     end
   end

ActiveAdmin.register Tool::Cvt::RemoteFocuLog do

~~~~
```

Answer (score -1):

Try `:hint => p.object.try(:snapshot).nil?` instead of `:hint => p.object.snapshot.nil?`

Comment: I got `undefined method `new_record?' for nil:NilClass`

Comment: Do you have a `accepts_nested_attributes_for :snapshots` in `Tool::Cvt::RemoteFocu` ActiveRecord model?

Comment: `accepts_nested_attributes_for :remote_focu_logs` don't `:snapshot`, sorry